# trying to use Google Sheets API, GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() gives 'System.AggregateException' error

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to follow the quickstart tutorial for Google Sheets .NET API [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet).

But when it gets to this line:

```
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

Here's what happens:

1. Internet Explorer opens.
2. Goes to `accounts.google.com` application authorization window.
3. I click `Allow`.
4. Get redirected to `localhost`. Get this message in IE.

---

```
This page can't be displayed

* Make sure the web address http://localhost:54538 is correct.
* Look for the page with your search engine.
* Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

5. In VS Express, this exception is thrown:

---

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: One or more errors occurred.
```

It's possible that there is a corporate IT security policy in place that is preventing me from accessing this `localhost` port; I tried directly typing "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" into the Chrome address bar, and in both cases got a "This site can’t be reached" error.

EDIT: My `client_id.json` file is as follows:

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"[long ID string].apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"angular-polygon-162522","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"[secret ID]","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

Comment: Try to check these SO questions [11122092](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122092/how-to-fix-system-aggregateexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll) and [30647119](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647119/system-aggregateexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll-when-using-signalr) if it can help you.

Comment: Do you have an http server running at "http://localhost:54538"? Did you try entering "http://localhost:54538" in your browser (you said you entered "http://localhost")? What do you expect to see next?

Comment: @pinoyyid, I entered `localhost:54538` in the browser and got "This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect."  I don't have an http server running there, I'm just trying to diagnose why `AuthorizeAsync()` is failing.

Comment: It's failing because you don't have an http server running on port 54538. What is in your credentials file (obfuscate any secrets)

Comment: @pinoyyid, I've added the contents of the `client_id.json` file that I received from Google when I registered the app, in the body of my question.

Comment: @pinoyyid, any further advice about this?  I'm just trying to automate some data entry into a Google Sheets document using C#, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Sure. let me ask, will it always be the same Sheet? or will each user of your app have his own sheet?

Comment: @pinoyyid, for this app, there will be multiple users all accessing the same sheet.

Comment: is your app running on a server, or is it distributed and installed to user's own PCs?

Comment: @pinoyyid, it may run on a server eventually, but for now I'd like to make it a standalone executable that each user can run on their own PC.

Comment: I suggest you create a Service Account. Your app will be able to authenticate to this using saved credentials. So no more 3-legged OAuth to worry about. You will need to share the spreadsheet with the email address of the Service Account so that it can be accessed.